# React - Combine connect export from react-redux and GoogleAPIWrapper from google-maps-react

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a component that relies on both `connect` from `react-redux` and `GoogleAPIWrapper` from `google-maps-react` and I am having trouble figuring out how to export my class using both.

Here's what my `connect` export looks like:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MapContainer);
```

and here's what my GoogleAPIWrapper export looks like:

```
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
})(MapContainer);
```

How can I export using both of these components together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MapContainer));
```

Or like this:

```
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MapContainer);

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
})(connector);
```